# Scala trait subclass constraint

Tags: scala, types, traits

I have a set of message base on a "Message" trait:

```
trait Message{
  id: Int
}

case class AckMsg(id: Int) extends Message
case class NackMsg(id: Int) extends Message
```

And having some function to take them as parameters:

```
def replyAck(ack: AckMsg) = { ... }

def replyNack(nack: NackMsg) = { ... }
```

When I am defining some higher level function to leverage the use of those function, I encountered:

```
def replyingMsg(fun: Message => Unit): Unit = { ... } 

replyingMsg(replyAck(AckMsg(id)))   //compiling error here!
```

The compiler doesn't like the fact that I have (Message => Unit) but passing (AckMsg => Unit)

So, how can I in replyingMsg, defining something like:

```
def replyingMsg(fun: M <: Message => Unit) //imagery code!!!
```

The above code is in error:

1. For some reason once involve <: Message cannot be a trait, need to be a class
2. <: doesn't seems to describing the situation correctly

How can I tell the compiler that I am passing something a subclass of a trait?
Please someone shed some light on the complicated type system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the following:

```
def replyingMsg[T <: Message](fun: T => Unit): Unit = { }
```

Saying fun is a function from T to Unit such that T is a subclass of Message. I'm not going to comment on the merits of the current design of using a Trait versus an abstract class, but I'd be interested if others had thoughts.

Comment: I am indeed following the pattern of Akka documentation recommended. Having a sealed Trait and then have set of message extends from it.  Just curious, What's the benefit using abstract class instead?

Comment: I myself don't know in this instance. In Scala, I get lost in the many ways of object modeling - in this instance, it looked like a classical object hierarchy and I think of traits more like Java interfaces.

Comment: To other viewer, this answer perfectly resolved the issue.  Thanks jimmyb.  And I think trait is much more than Java interfaces while I look more and more in others Scala code. Specially when it comes to cake pattern, I agree it is a bit abusing but can't deny that make my development life much easier. (And the code is cleaner)

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem, that first-class functions (replyAck _) and (replyNack _) are actually traits of type Function1[-Message,+Unit], so they are in contrvariant position to Message.

If you still want to follow this pattern and use method def replyingMsg(fun: Message => Unit): Unit without a change, you can solve this in many ways. For example using pf:

```
def replyingMsg(fun: Message => Unit): Unit = {println("success")}

scala> def replyAck: Message => Unit = {case AckMsg(id) => Unit}
replyAck: Message => Unit

scala> replyingMsg(replyAck)
success
```